# ExpandableListView - setOnChildClickListener and get Parent/Group view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can i have access to group view by setOnChildClickListener() ?

I want to change the group item background when the child has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in `OnChildClickListener#onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)` you have groupPosition.

You should have a back-up model with model data for both groups and children. On call to above method you would say something like: getModelData().getGroupItem(groupPosition).setValue(some_custom_value).

And then call `parent#notifyDataSetInvalidated();` That will trigger a full layout and redraw for list.

Within `getGroupView()` you should have some logic to determine how to draw the background based on above getModelData().getValue().